# How to fix 500 internal error in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I'm Really getting trouble solving 500 internal error in restapi.

When I make GET and POST request working fine but when I make PUT,DELETE and findById GET request not working. if I try to make a request it will show 500 internal error. I don't know why it is happening so please help me.
Thank you in Advance!
Family1.class

```
@Entity
public class Family1 {
    
    @Id 
    private long id;
    private String Name;
    private int Member;
    private long contactNo;
    @Embedded
    public Address address;
// getters,setters
```

Family1Controller.class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/family1")
public class Family1Controller {
    
    @Autowired
    private Family1Service family1Service;

@RequestMapping("/fam1")
    public List<Family1> getAllFamily1(){
        return family1Service.getAllFamily1();
    }
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,value="/fam1") 
    public void addFamily1(@RequestBody Family1 family1){
        family1Service.addFamily1(family1);   
     }
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET,value="/fam1/{id}")
    public Family1 getFamily1Id(@PathVariable long id) {
        List<Family1> family=family1Service.getFamily1Id(id);
        return family.get((int) id);
}
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT,value="/fam1/{id}")
     public Family1 updateFamily1(@RequestBody Family1 family1, @PathVariable("id") long id){
        family1.setId(id);
        return family1Service.updateFamily1(family1);   
    }
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.DELETE,value="/fam1/{id}")
    public void deleteFamily1(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        family1Service.deleteFamily1(id);
    }

}
```

Family1Service.class

```
@Service
public class Family1Service {
    
    private Family1Repository family1Repository;
     
    private List<Family1> family=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            new Family1(1,"abc",3,32423423,new Address("east street","xxxxxx",23456)),
            new Family1(2,"xyz",4,354646,new Address("west street","yyyyyy",23456)),
            ));
    
    public  List<Family1> getAllFamily1() {
        return family;
    }
    public List<Family1> getFamily1Id(long id){
        family1Repository.findById(id);
        return family;
    }
    public void addFamily1(Family1 family1) {
        family.add(family1);
    }
    
    public Family1 updateFamily1(Family1 family1) {
        return family1Repository.save(family1); 
    }
    public void deleteFamily1(long id) {
        family1Repository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

Family1Repository.class

```
public interface Family1Repository extends CrudRepository<Family1, String>  {

    public void deleteById(long id);

    public void save(Family1 family1, long id);

    public void findById(long id);
```

Family1application.class

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
public class Family1Application {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Family1Application.class, args);
        
            }
       
}
```

error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-01-06T07:32:49.232+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/family1/fam1/1"
}
```

Comment: why don't you try to debug or put some try catch to see what is the actual error? Internal server error is a generic error..

Comment: Can you add the server side logs? they should have a detailed stack trace of the underlying cause.

Comment: how to add server-side logs can you please explain to me? I'm new to spring boot

Comment: am not sure about what this Family1Repository is doing but the GET and POST is adding and getting things from List<Family1> family not from the Family1Repository. Check the server console in your IDE to get the  server logs

Comment: The Repository is also not corresponding correctly to the Family1 entity. The repository expects a `String` ID field, but Family1 uses `long`. You might want to change it to: `public interface Family1Repository extends CrudRepository<Family1, long>`

Comment: actually you are right the problem will come Family1Repository side. I will try it

Comment: I changed String to long in the repository it will also not working

Comment: Did you check the server log like @Sameer mentioned? The 500 should create a stacktrace on the Spring Boot side.

Comment: Also the `addFamily1` method in your service does not call the repository. So nothing will be added to the database. `getFamily1Id` does nothing with the result of the repository call and simply returns the List. The List entries do not exist in the database, this could be the source of your problems.

Comment: I checked server logs it will show error like this cannot invoke the save(object) it will be null

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the call to a predefined list with calls to the repository. The elements in the list have no representation in the database, therefore they are invalid when you use those IDs to delete objects with the repository.

You might want to try something like this:

```java
@Service
public class Family1Service {
    
    private Family1Repository family1Repository;
    
    public  List<Family1> getAllFamily1() {
        return family1Repository.findAll();
    }

    public Family1 getFamily1Id(long id){
        return family1Repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(); 
        // This returns an Optional orElseThrow will create an error if nothing is found
    }

    public void addFamily1(Family1 family1) {
        family1Repository.save(family1);
    }
    
    public Family1 updateFamily1(Family1 family1) {
        return family1Repository.save(family1); 
    }

    public void deleteFamily1(long id) {
        family1Repository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

And in the controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/family1")
public class Family1Controller {
    
    @Autowired
    private Family1Service family1Service;

    @RequestMapping("/fam1")
    public List<Family1> getAllFamily1(){
        return family1Service.getAllFamily1();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/fam1") 
    public void addFamily1(@RequestBody Family1 family1){
        family1Service.addFamily1(family1);   
     }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/fam1/{id}")
    public Family1 getFamily1Id(@PathVariable long id) {
        return family1Service.getFamily1Id(id);
     }

     @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT, value="/fam1")
     public Family1 updateFamily1(@RequestBody Family1 family1){
        return family1Service.updateFamily1(family1);   
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.DELETE, value="/fam1/{id}")
    public void deleteFamily1(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        family1Service.deleteFamily1(id);
    }
}
```

```java
public interface Family1Repository extends CrudRepository<Family1, long>  {
    // All repository methods you need are already provided by the CrudRepository
}
```

I removed the List you used in the `Family1Service` to avoid data not being present in the database. This might lead to an empty result when calling the `findAll()` method of the repository.

Note that I did not have time to fully test this, but the general approach should work.

Comment: @SebastianThanks for working. Above your mentioned all things to be right but when I access the database in localhost:8081/ it will show a Whitelabel error. I tried many ways but it is didn't work for me.

Comment: The controller you posted only handles paths starting with `/family1`. This means that you need to call the REST endpoint like this (with GET): `localhost:8081/family1/fam1` to get all `Family1` entities in your database or an empty list if the database is empty.

Comment: If you want to add a new entry to your database, you need to create a POST request and send the data in the POST body to the endpoint: `localhost:8081/family1/fam1`. These are the same calls you had to do before my changes.

Comment: when I make a post request I got a 500 internal server error how is it possible to save the database

Comment: The stacktrace from the Spring Boot app should tell you more about the problem, hopefully.